# Why can't I print out this matrix/2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to type in a matrix and then print it, using functions. 
The program crashes when it gets to the read_mat function. What am I getting wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** insert_mat(int **mat, int r, int c);


int** read_mat(int** mat, int r, int c)
{
    mat = (int**)calloc(r,sizeof(int*));
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        mat[i]=(int*)calloc(c,sizeof(int));
    }
    insert_mat(mat, r, c);
    return mat;

}


int** insert_mat(int **mat, int r, int c)
{
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            printf("\nmat[%d][%d] = ",i , j);
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return mat;
}

void print_mat(int **mat, int r, int c)
{
    printf("\n");

    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",mat[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}



int main()
{
    int **mat;
    int r1 =2;
    int c1 = 2;
    read_mat(mat, r1, c1);
    print_mat(mat, r1, c1);

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried printing elements of mat in main (ex: printf("%d", mat[0][0]);) and it is also not working. So maybe the error is when I insert the elements? But I am not sure what I do wrong.

Comment: "program chrashes" and "is not working" is not very helpful. Please provide the full error message you get if the compiler prints out any at the attempt of compilation.

Comment: You don't assign the return value of read_mat() to `mat` and you pass it by value, so `mat` remains uninitialized.